# Getting absolute path of directory

Tags: python

How do I get the absolute path of a directory (it has to be any directory, not the current one!) in Python?

I tried with `os.path.listdir()` but it yields only the relative one.
Thanks!

Comment: Without any context of where that directory lives, you cannot. `os.listdir()` (no `.path`) lists filenames (including directories), which are *always* relative.

Comment: And how would you pass what directory you wanted to this function without knowing the full path already? I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 4):

Using `os.path.abspath`:

```
In [259]: for fname in os.listdir('.'):
     ...:     print os.path.abspath(fname)
     ...:     
D:\Documents\Desktop\t\old-linear
D:\Documents\Desktop\t\ZC_a0_3.xml
```

If you're trying to pass a `path` to `os.listdir`, then use `os.path.join`:

```
In [266]: path=r'D:\Documents\Desktop\ttt'
     ...: for fname in os.listdir(path):
     ...:     print os.path.join(path, fname)

D:\Documents\Desktop\ttt\old-linear
D:\Documents\Desktop\ttt\t6916A_a0_0.xml
D:\Documents\Desktop\ttt\t6916A_a0_1.xml
```

Comment: I believe `i` is a bad name for a path iteration variable. Consider `name` or `file_name`

Comment: I only need the absolute path for the DIRECTORY, not the absolute path itself

Comment: Referring to the example, I'd like to know how to get: "D:\Documents\Desktop\ttt\"

Comment: @Krishath then use the first example. The 2nd example shows how do you get files' abspath when you are listing files from a different path.